# React controlled input warning: "A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled"

Tags: html, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, tailwind-css

I'm encountering a warning in my React application related to controlled and uncontrolled input elements. The warning message is as follows:

```
client.js:1 Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen.
```

Here is the code:

```
const fetchUser = async () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
            
            const res = await fetch(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HOST}/api/getuser`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ token }),
            })

            const response = await res.json()
            setData({ name: response.user.name, address: response.user.address, mobile: response.user.mobile, email: response.user.email, password: response.user.password })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
            router.push('/login')
        }
        else{
            fetchUser()
        }
    }, [router.query])

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="rounded-lg border bg-card text-card-foreground shadow-sm w-full max-w-2xl mx-auto mt-5" data-v0-t="card">
                <div className="flex flex-col space-y-1.5 p-6">
                    <h3 className="text-2xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap leading-none tracking-tight">User Account</h3>
                    <p className="text-sm text-muted-foreground">Update your account information.</p>
                </div>
                <div className="p-6 space-y-4">
                    <div className="space-y-2">
                        <label
                            className="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70"
                            htmlFor="name"
                        >
                            Name
                        </label>
                        <input
                            className="flex h-10 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50"
                            id="name"
                            type='text'
                            value={data.name}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            fdprocessedid="fteemd"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="space-y-2">
                        <label
                            className="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70"
                            htmlFor="email"
                        >
                            Email
                        </label>
                        <input
                            className="flex h-10 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50"
                            id="email"
                            type="email"
                            readOnly={true}
                            value={data.email}
                            onChange={e => setData({email: e.target.value})}
                            fdprocessedid="z9hqe5"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="space-y-2">
                        <label
                            className="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70"
                            htmlFor="password"
                        >
                            Password
                        </label>
                        <input
                            className="flex h-10 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50"
                            id="password"
                            type="password"
                            readOnly={true}
                            onChange={e => setData({email: e.target.value})}
                            value={data.password}
                            fdprocessedid="cpy1es"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="space-y-2">
                        <label
                            className="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70"
                            htmlFor="mobile"
                        >
                            Mobile
                        </label>
                        <input
                            className="flex h-10 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50"
                            id="mobile"
                            type="tel"
                            value={data.mobile}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            fdprocessedid="qenvtf"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="space-y-2">
                        <label
                            className="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70"
                            htmlFor="address"
                        >
                            Address (Default)
                        </label>
                        <textarea
                            className="flex w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50 min-h-[100px]"
                            id="address"
                            value={data.address}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                        ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className="grid grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                        <div className="space-y-2">
                            <label
                                className="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70"
                                htmlFor="state"
                            >
                                State
                            </label>
                            <input
                                className="flex h-10 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50"
                                id="state"
                                type='text'
                                value={data.state}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                fdprocessedid="q5kxoq"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="space-y-2">
                            <label
                                className="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70"
                                htmlFor="city"
                            >
                                City
                            </label>
                            <input
                                className="flex h-10 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50"
                                id="city"
                                type='text'
                                value={data.city}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                fdprocessedid="zvwpe"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="space-y-2">
                        <label
                            className="text-sm font-medium leading-none peer-disabled:cursor-not-allowed peer-disabled:opacity-70"
                            htmlFor="pincode"
                        >
                            Pincode
                        </label>
                        <input
                            className="flex h-10 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50"
                            id="pincode"
                            type='tel'
                            value={data.pincode}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            fdprocessedid="oxo1n6"
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="flex items-center p-6">
                    <button
                        className="inline-flex items-center justify-center whitespace-nowrap rounded-md text-sm font-medium ring-offset-background transition-colors focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50 bg-primary text-primary-foreground hover:bg-primary/90 h-10 px-4 py-2 ml-auto bg-pink-500 hover:bg-pink-600 text-white"
                        fdprocessedid="qb629"
                    >
                        Update
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have a React component that fetches user data asynchronously and updates the state accordingly. I'm using controlled input elements to handle user input. However, I'm encountering the warning mentioned above, and I suspect it's related to the asynchronous nature of data fetching

How can I troubleshoot and resolve the "changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled" warning in React?

I'm seeking guidance on resolving the warning and improving the code structure for better handling of controlled input elements, especially regarding the password field.

Answer (score 1):

the undefined error occurs if your input element is controlled by state and the value is undefined. This must be due to way you have defined data Object in you code. can you post the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

```
<input className="flex h-10 w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-background px-3 py-2 text-sm ring-offset-background file:border-0 file:bg-transparent file:text-sm file:font-medium placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50"
                            id="password"
                            type="password"
                            readOnly={true}
                            onChange={e => setData({email: e.target.value})}
                            value={data.password}
                            fdprocessedid="cpy1es"
                        />
```

the `onChange={e => setData({email: e.target.value})}` could be the culprit.
Here you are not updating the `email` key's value in the `data` object, rather you are entirely replacing it with just the email.

You need to pass the whole object and then update the email key's value. This is also the the recommended way in React docu.
`onChange={e => setData(prevData => ({...prevData, email: e.target.value}))}`

https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state#copying-objects-with-the-spread-syntax